# How to create a custom form template in magento from admin panel?

Tags: template, forms

[image]
I had used web-forms extension which was a very good solution but my main problem is it is only allowing to create 10 fields whereas my form contains 18 fields... please provide a solution for this... thanks in advance

Comment: "it is only allowing to create 10 fields". means?

Comment: @KeyulShah : it means that i had to create a custom form with 18-20 fields  using WebForms: Community Edition i got the solution to create a custom form but it is only allows to create 10 fields only (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webforms-community-edition.html)

Comment: The Community Edition limitation
Manage up to 3 web-forms
**Add up to 10 fields**

Comment: hmm you are using custom extension it might allow only 10 fields. for that you have to contact to support team of this extension

Comment: there is a option that i have to buy the professional edition which cost me $30 but i dont want to go with it...

Comment: if you buy then definitely you ask him to give support

Comment: i havent purchased the professional edition yet

Comment: check module js file from where this alert message coming. if you disable this message then may be you can add new fields

Comment: yeah m searching for that only... mate

Comment: check in js folder or in skin/frontend/default

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple: buy the Professional Version for $89. The 10 fields limit is a limitation of the free version of this extension.

Obviously, you're satisfied with the extension. Then why spend so much time on getting around the limitations?